# How to add an alarm to CountDownTimer?

Tags: java, android, timer, countdown, alarm

How would you add an alarm to the `CountDownTimer` class? I guess it would be in the `onFinish()` method that comes with it, but just how would you go about that? Some code would help a lot.

Comment: developer.android.com should be your best friend https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that extends CountDownTimer, then override the on finish method and add a alarm function there.

```
    object : NewCountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
        override fun onFinish() {
            super.onFinish()
            Timber.d("Test new countdowntimer2")
        }
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {

        }

    }.start()




open class NewCountDownTimer(millisInFuture: Long, millisUntilFinished:Long) : CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, millisUntilFinished) 
{
    override fun onFinish() {
        Timber.d("Test new countdowntimer")
        //Add alarm function Here
    }

    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
    }

}
```